# Custom Android keyboard without KeyboardView

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have seen lots of answers on SO and tutorials on internet on custom keyboard development. However, all of them use KeyboardView for displaying keyboard. It is difficult to manage KeyboardView and KeyboardView does not show custom layouts. Is there any other way to implement custom keyboard app that shows custom layouts?

Answer (score 1):

In your InputMethodService, there's a function onCreateInputView.  It returns the main view of your keyboard.  You can have it return any view you want, including a custom one.  In fact I don't think any serious keyboards actually use KeyboardView-  it's too limiting.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to force calling onCreateInputView when key of keyboard is pressed?

Comment: No, it's called once when the service is started. But you then have a view and a window token, so you can always alert your own layout to add additional views, such as for key pop ups.

Comment: Can you please explain how?

Comment: Can you please tell where shall I write code for layout?

Comment: Any solutions observed for custom keyboard without keypad?